# Aerogear Cordova Push is not defined

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build, aerogear

this is my first hybrid app. I am targeting Android 4.x, but testing with Android 6.x. My development is with build.phonegap.com

I have been developing cordova mobile app and need to integrate background push notifciation.

And I used aero gear push and install that plugin to my app.

But still my device was not registering and show error "push is not defined"

I can't fix it. my thought that is aero gear push javascript file was not included. Do i need to call the js file in index.html?

**cordova -verson**
5.4.1

**cordova platform list**
Installed platforms: android 4.1.1
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, webos, win
dows, windows8, wp8

**cordova plugin list**
aerogear-cordova-push 2.0.4 "
    AeroGear PushPlugin
  "
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
es6-promise-plugin 3.0.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.8 "Keyboard"

Comment: Are you testing from a browser?

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 : Is this your first hybrid App? - **Yes**
Are you using the Desktop App? - **No**
What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? **target platform Android 4 but testing device had Android 6**
Are you using CLI, SDK or Build ? **build.phonegap.com**

Comment: @venkatesh this will be my only message to you. You have a problem following directions. Problems and questions with a 3rd-party plugin should go to the author of the plugin. Best of Luck

Comment: I have found that no plugin was detected in phonegap build. In plugins tab, the following message shown "This application has no plugins.".
http://screenshot.net/qx0y7cq.jpg